# Can I render Thymeleaf templates manually from a String?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an upcoming project which has the following requirements:

- Very simple to use (end-users will be expected to use it)
- Java based, the project will be written in Spring3
- String based loading (although open to similar suggestions) as I will be storing the templates in a database, not as files

The tricky part of this seems to be getting a templating engine to load the template from the database.

I quite like the look of Thymeleaf, but I have no idea how to render the template manually from a string - has anybody tried this?

I am open to suggestions for a better technology for the job, but this is my preference.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this:

#### 1. Add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

OR, if you are not use spring boot, you can just add thymeleaf dependency.

#### 2. Config resolver

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class TemplateEngineConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/mail/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

#### 3. Create your template

`src/main/resources/templates/mail/myfile.html`:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <div th:text="${myDivContent}"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### 4. Render the template using `org.thymeleaf.context.Context`

```java
    Context myContext = new Context();
    myContext.setVariable("myDivContent", "Hello, the weather is foggy");

    String htmlTemplate = templateEngine.process(templateName, myContext);
```

The `templateName` is a string variable. The `templateContext` is a `org.thymeleaf.context.Context` impl.

Comment: how do we initialize the templateContext bean? should that be in Step 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the UrlTemplateResolver? Maybe you could expose the templates through a REST interface so you could access the raw template via a URL. I've never tried this but seems possible. Otherwise, you would likely need to implement your own template resolver. Thymeleaf comes with servlet, file, url, and classloader template resolvers. You would basically need to write one for MongoDB.

See http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.17/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/package-summary.html

Comment: I will try this, it looks like a nicer solution than I had in mind